# Printing a populated array of strings prints garbage

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'm just getting into C with a previous knowledge of RPG coding. Like many before me, I'm confused about strings, arrays and pointers and how to work with them.

I'm working on a program which takes the name, equatorial radius and polar radius of the planets from a data file, and then calculates and outputs volume, surface area.

My main function has the following declarations:

```
double       equi_rad[iNumPlanets]; /* equitoral radii of planets */
double       pol_rad[iNumPlanets];  /* polar radii of planets */
char         *name[iNumPlanets];    /* array containing planet name */
```

(`iNumPlanets` has already been initialized as 8)

I then call the function `load`:

```
load("radii.dat", equi_rad, pol_rad, iNumPlanets, name);
```

Load reads through the file in a loop and populates arrays. I've verified that this is working correctly within the function, so there seems no point copying out this bit of code. This is the prototype:

```
int load(const char* filename, double *equitoral_radii, double *polar_radii, const int iNumPlanets, char *planet_name[]);
```

Back in my main function, the `equi_rad` and `pol_rad` arrays are populated correctly and can be worked with. However, when I try to `printf` the `name` array contents, it's just random nonsense.

Can anyone explain why I can successfully modify the `double` arrays in a function, but not the string arrays?

Comment: Could you show us how you are populating `name`?

Comment: and also how you're printing name[index]

Comment: `Load reads through the file in a loop and populates arrays. I've verified that this is working correctly within the function, so there seems no point copying out this bit of code.` seems to be at odds with `Back in my main function, the equi_rad and pol_rad arrays are populated correctly and can be worked with. However when I try to printf the name array contents, it's just random nonsense.`. It seems that we need to see the code for `load`, along with the contents of `radii.dat`...

Comment: Since your question is with regards to the C language, can you please simplify things here, in order to make it easier for us to read it? For example, change those array names to `arr1`, `arr2` and `arr3`. Unless you want to ask something specific about calculating the volume and surface area of planets, there is honestly no need to specify all these weary details within the question. They just make it harder to focus on the actual problem.

Comment: The issue is inside `load()` for which you do *not* show the code. So how could we help you then? a

Comment: You are aware that `name` isn't an array of "strings" but of pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Back in my main function, the equi_rad and pol_rad arrays are
>   populated correctly and can be worked with. However when I try to
>   printf the name array contents, it's just random nonsense.

You need to show the code. Guess is you are not correctly populating `planet_name` array. You might need to use `malloc` (e.g., `planet_name[i] = malloc(LENGTH)`), and copy the string contents there. Then you should have no issues. e.g.

```
planet_name[i] = malloc(strlen(sourceStr)+1);
strcpy(planet_name[i], sourceStr);
```

Don't forget to `free` each of the pointers for which you allocated data.

Comment: Isn't this just a comment?

Comment: @WeatherVane: Well I also posted a solution in the answer to a very *likely* issue the OP has

Comment: @WeatherVane: It's a solution based on a very likley assumption .. so well

Comment: Brilliant, that worked! Thanks!
Now I'm going to go back and reread the bit of the tutorial that discussed malloc()

Comment: @MTrevers: nice if it helped; don't forget `free`

Comment: @giorgi Good guess! I'll upvote since the OP liked it and I was negative.

Comment: @giorgi I would have preferred `malloc(1+strlen(sourceStr));`